# Using cosine distance with scikit learn KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

Is it possible  to use something like 1 - cosine similarity with scikit learn's KNeighborsClassifier?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032628/why-does-scikit-learns-nearest-neighbor-doesnt-seem-to-return-proper-cosine-si) answer says no, but on the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) for KNeighborsClassifier, it says the metrics mentioned in [DistanceMetrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) are available. Distance metrics don't include an explicit cosine distance, probably because it's not really a distance, but supposedly it's possible to input a function into the metric. I tried inputting the scikit learn linear kernel into KNeighborsClassifier but it gives me an error that the function needs two arrays as arguments. Anyone else tried this?

Comment: KNN classifier is likely to use some optimizations which rely on triangle inequality. The cosine metric doesn't obey it, so correct behavior of KNN is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe the cosine metric can be made to obey the triangle inequality, and the same ordering can be achieved without an explicit implementation anyway. See my answer for details

Comment: It is not clear to me if it is not possible to use why now is explicitly inside the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#kdtree-and-balltree-classes) Something changed during these years?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The cosine similarity is generally defined as x<sup>T</sup> y / (||x|| * ||y||), and outputs 1 if they are the same and goes to -1 if they are completely different. This definition is not technically a metric, and so you can't use accelerating structures like ball and kd trees with it. If you force scikit learn to use the brute force approach, you should be able to use it as a distance if you pass it your own custom distance metric object. There are methods of transforming the cosine similarity into a valid distance metric if you would like to use ball trees (you can find one in the [JSAT library](https://github.com/EdwardRaff/JSAT))

Notice though, that x<sup>T</sup> y / (||x|| * ||y||) = (x/||x||)<sup>T</sup> (y/||y||). The euclidean distance can be equivalently written as sqrt(x<sup>T</sup>x + y<sup>T</sup>y − 2 x<sup>T</sup>y). If we normalize every datapoint before giving it to the KNeighborsClassifier, then `x^T x = 1` for all `x`. So the euclidean distance will degrade to  `sqrt(2 − 2x^T y)`. For completely the same inputs, we would get `sqrt(2-2*1) = 0` and for complete opposites `sqrt(2-2*-1)= 2`. And it is clearly a simple shape, so you can get the same ordering as the cosine distance by normalizing your data and then using the euclidean distance. So long as you use the `uniform` weights option, the results will be identical to having used a correct Cosine Distance.

Comment: It was too simple. Thanks Raff for this elegant solution :)

Comment: Will this work if the values are positive and negative? Like do you have to change the normalisation?

Comment: This will work for any values, positive or negative. You just need to divide each vector by its 2-norm.

Answer (score 1):

KNN family class constructors have a parameter called `metric`, you can switch between different distance metrics you want to use in nearest neighbour model.
A list of available distance metrics can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html)

If you want to use cosine metric for ranking and classification problem, you can use norm 2 Euclidean distance on normalized feature vector, that gives you same ranking/classification (predictions that made by argmax or argmin operations) results.

Comment: As already observed in the question. That list does not mention the cosine distance.

Comment: @oulenz He is saying norm(data) w/ l2 (euclidean) is the same as cosine(data) since euclidean is angle + magnitude whereas cosine is just angle (magnitudes are not a factor as the data is normalized to unit vector length).

Comment: @Maximus12793 Yes, that part was edited in after my comment.