# Optimization of two for loop

Tags: python, performance, optimization

How can optimze below code.
take example of

```
x_tsvd = [[1,2,3,4],[5,4,5,6],[2,4,5,5]]
svd_tfidf=[[11,3,4,5],[4,4,6,7],[6,6,3,5]]
```

The number of row are very large((4 million) above is just an example.Basically i have to calculate cosine similarity for each row of x_tsvd with svd_tfidf.
Is there any way i can optimize it further to speed up.

```
for i in range(len(x_tsvd)):
    array_=[]
    for j in range (len(svd_tfidf)):
        cosine_similarity_=np.dot(x_tsvd[i],svd_tfidf[j])/(norm(x_tsvd[i])*norm(svd_tfidf[j]))
        array_.append(cosine_similarity_)
    index=np.array(array_).argsort()
```

Comment: "Basically i have to calculate cosine similarity for each row of x_tsvd with svd_tfidf." To be clear: you wish to calculate 16 trillion results and store them all? How much memory do you expect this to require?

Comment: How are you going to store the result?  Technically you will have an index (4 million vector) for each `i` (1 to 4 million), usually this won't fit the memory of a typical PC.  Are you going to store them as a file?

Comment: yes i will save it

Comment: Do you really need a 4Mx4M matrix?  Or, for each element in x_tsvd are you trying to find the N nearest neighbors (say 10) in svd_tfidf for each element in x_tsvd?  In the later case, you have a 4M x N (say 4M x 10) size data structure which is much more manageable.  See [Using cosine distance with scikit learn KNeighborsClassifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144632/using-cosine-distance-with-scikit-learn-kneighborsclassifier)

Comment: I want or part that yo have metioned

Answer (score 1):

Mainly through the following points to accelerate:

1. `numpy.linalg.norm` function can calculate the norm along the axis. For 2D arrays, specify `axis` as 1 to calculate the Euclidean norm for each row.
2. By broadcasting, the elements between two norm vectors can be multiplied in pairs.
3. `numpy.ndarray.dot` method can be used between 2D arrays to calculate inner product in pairs.
4. `numpy.ndarray.argsort` method can sort along the axis.

```
>>> x_tsvd = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 5, 5]]
>>> svd_tfidf = [[11, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 6, 7], [6, 6, 3, 5]]
>>> x = np.array(x_tsvd)
>>> y = np.array(svd_tfidf)
>>> norm_prod = np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1)[:, None] * np.linalg.norm(y, axis=1)
>>> similarities = x.dot(y.T) / norm_prod
>>> similarities.argsort(axis=1)
array([[0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating 4Mx4M similarity matrix we can create a neighborhood similarity matrix, where:

- K is the k-nearest neighbor similarity of each observations in x_tsvd to svd_tfid
- Resulting similarity is 4MxK

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

def nearest_neighbors(x, y, k = 3):
    '''
        For each element of x, finds its k-nearest neighbors in y
        
        Technique:
            Neighbors are based upon cosine similarity
            Converts cosine similarity to a Eucliean distance
            based upon:
                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144632/using-cosine-distance-with-scikit-learn-kneighborsclassifier/34145444#34145444
            
        
        Returns:
            - Distances to k nearest neighbors
            - Indices to to k nearest neighbors
    '''
    # Normalize each sample of input
    x = normalize(x_tsvd, axis = 1)  
    y = normalize(svd_tfidf, axis = 1) 
    
    # Form the BallTree
    tree = BallTree(x, metric='euclidean')

    # Get distances and indices to k nearest neighbors
    distances, indices = tree.query(y, k = k)
    
    # map distnaces to similarity
    # transform distances back to similarity i.e. similariy = (2 - d**2)/2
    return (2 - distances*distances)/2, indices
```

**Test**

```
x_tsvd = [[1,2,3,4],[5,4,5,6],[2,4,5,5]]
svd_tfidf=[[11,3,4,5],[4,4,6,7],[6,6,3,5]]
similarity, indices = nearest_neighbors(x_tsvd, svd_tfidf, k = 2)

print(f'Similarity Matrix\n {similarity}\n')
print(f'Index of Matches of x_tsvd in svd_tfidf\n {indices}')
```

**Output**

```
Similarity Matrix
 [[0.88590616 0.72207119]
 [0.98862307 0.98344042]
 [0.95209915 0.88229057]]

Index of Matches of x_tsvd in svd_tfidf
 [[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

**Explanation**

We use Balltree to find K nearest neighbor.  However:

- Similarity is not a distance metric
- We use the technique from [Using cosine distance with scikit learn KNeighborsClassifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144632/using-cosine-distance-with-scikit-learn-kneighborsclassifier/34145444#34145444) to transform similarity to distances
- Create Balltree using Euclidean distance on normalized data
- Euclidean distance of each x, y vector using normalized data will be sqrt(2 − 2*x^T y)
- With x, y normalized, x^T y is the similarity.  Thus, we have transformed similarity to a distance metric
- Query Balltree to obtain distances and indices of K nearest neighbors x_tsvd observations in svd_tfidf
- Convert distances back to similarity using inverse transformation